# Storing complex objects in web.config

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, inversion-of-control

I am basically wanting to fetch an IDIctionary from a place which is global setting repository. We basically use IOC and I had put it there but for certain reasons , it has to be moved to web.config. I have gone through some articles and the nearest I got was  this:

> http://brijbhushan.net/2011/04/21/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-web-config/

Again this article talks about storing it programmatically. I just want something simple where a programmer can come at the design time and store or change my dictionary and that's it. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: <MyDictionary>
     <add key="name1" value="value1" />
     <add key="name2" value="value2" />
     <add key="name3" value="value3" />
     <add key="name4" value="value4" />
  </MyDictionary>  But value here is still string I need something like int[].

Comment: Take a look at this VS extension http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/def289f1-377d-4cd0-802a-80c8be8b6758

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web.config file is not really a good place to store and deserialize objects from. I would recommend using XAML files for this purpose. This is much more appropriate and done by MS themselves. You can get more information here http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2009/05/18/xaml-in-net-4-0-serialization-and-deserialization-using-xamlservices.aspx.

Comment: Hi I am sorry for the late reply. That was helpful. Thanks for the comments.